# Could not find an open port at xxx.heroku.com

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am trying to deploy a react frontend on heroku. I use the proxy in pacakage.json so at first I had the "Invalid Host Header" error. Then after I created a .env.development file with the Host specified to my heroku domain I get the error "could not find an open port at xxx.heroku.com

Looking for guidance on how to get it running or to find a port lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue and found that i was using default buildpack. I fixed issue by using [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)
In app.json add create-react-app-buildpack

```
{
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack"
    }
  ]
}
```

Create static.json if you have not created

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "proxies": {
    "/route": {
      "origin": "url"
    }
  }
}
```

In case if you face nigix 404 on page refresh, please add below to static.json

```
"routes": {
    "/**": "default.html"
  }
```

In my case default.html is index.html

Remove proxy from package.json, But you have to retain it for local working.
Remove HOST from heroku
and change buildpack from heroku cli, In my case i cleared all buildpacks and added new build pack. BUILPACK_URL https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:add BUILDPACK_URL
```

`heroku buildpacks:set BUILDPACK_URL`

Finally push code to heroku. You can follow this [doc](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/machinio/create-react-app-buildpack)